# plot a column of a data.frame in r using ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame 'test' that's similar to this:

```
names  mean
a        1   
b        2
c        3
d        4
```

I want to draw a boxplot only for the 'mean' column. How can I do this using ggplot2?

I tried this but it won't work:

```
qplot(mean, data=test, geom="boxplot") + geom_jitter()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `geom_boxplot` requires variables for both axes. In your example you have only one variable and you have mapped it to the x variable, because that is the one named first in `qplot`. If you want to draw only one boxplot (all values belonging to the same group) you should create a variable in the `test` data.frame that has the same value for each row. This would give you what you are after.

```
test <- data.frame(
  names = letters[1:4],
  mean = 1:4,
  x = "group")

qplot(x, mean, data = test, geom = "boxplot")
```